# Client-side routing and 404 on Github Pages URIs after refresh

Tags: javascript, github-pages

This is probably more of Github Pages question than a JS one.

I was following a tutorial on [VanillaJS SPA](https://github.com/dcode-youtube/single-page-app-vanilla-js). I'm finding when I push it to Github Pages with [`gh-pages`](https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages), while the routing works if you start on `/` and click the various nav links, you will see the URI update accordingly to `/posts`, `/settings`, etc.

However, if I refresh a page on `/posts`, `/settings`, etc., or try to go to any route other than `/`, I get a 404 error from Github.

The reason for this, I'm sure, is the application is just doing DOM manipulation and updating the URI string in the browser. Github Page's webserver knows how to handle `/`, but it is looking for actual subdirectories when it comes to `/posts`, `/settings`, etc. which don't really exist outside of DOM manipulation.

**I'm just curious if there is a way to get the client-side routing to work with Github Pages, or if this will just not work and creating subdirectories to correspond to these routes is the only way?**

This is the routing code:

```
import Dashboard from "./views/Dashboard.js";
import Posts from "./views/Posts.js";
import PostView from "./views/PostView.js";
import Settings from "./views/Settings.js";

const pathToRegex = path => new RegExp("^" + path.replace(/\//g, "\\/").replace(/:\w+/g, "(.+)") + "$");

const getParams = match => {
    const values = match.result.slice(1);
    const keys = Array.from(match.route.path.matchAll(/:(\w+)/g)).map(result => result[1]);

    return Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key, i) => {
        return [key, values[i]];
    }));
};

const navigateTo = url => {
    history.pushState(null, null, url);
    router();
};

const router = async () => {
    const routes = [
        { path: "/", view: Dashboard },
        { path: "/posts", view: Posts },
        { path: "/posts/:id", view: PostView },
        { path: "/settings", view: Settings }
    ];

    // Test each route for potential match
    const potentialMatches = routes.map(route => {
        return {
            route: route,
            result: location.pathname.match(pathToRegex(route.path))
        };
    });

    let match = potentialMatches.find(potentialMatch => potentialMatch.result !== null);

    if (!match) {
        match = {
            route: routes[0],
            result: [location.pathname]
        };
    }

    const view = new match.route.view(getParams(match));

    document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = await view.getHtml();
};

window.addEventListener("popstate", router);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (e.target.matches("[data-link]")) {
            e.preventDefault();
            navigateTo(e.target.href);
        }
    });

    router();
});
```

I didn't use the this `server.js` because I didn't see how `express` would work with Github Pages:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(
  '/static',
  express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'static'))
);

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, () => console.log('Server running...'));
```

Comment: The express server handles the routing since there is no real posts.html or settings.html. When that is not running, GitHub will try to find actual HTML pages which don't exist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot use URL navigation, but would have to implement SPA `#` hashtag navigation.
GitHub Pages would otherwise just support [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/), not URL rewrites alike Firebase hosting.

Just edit [`index.html`](https://github.com/dcode-youtube/single-page-app-vanilla-js/blob/master/frontend/index.html) and the `routes`:

```
<nav class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link" data-link>Dashboard</a>
    <a href="#posts" class="nav__link" data-link>Posts</a>
    <a href="#settings" class="nav__link" data-link>Settings</a>
</nav>
```

Clicking these will emit `popstate` event.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub Pages is meant for static websites only. That means that it provides no options for setting up a server (where you could use your Node.js/Express code) or allowing dynamic page routing.

It does, however, allow you to have a custom 404 page, which you can use as a workaround to this:

Move your main logic to a file named `404.html`, that will then be served everytime the path the user requested doesn't really exist.

One downside of this approach is that you can't limit the scope of that on your website, so you'll have to create a special case for really not found paths manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a 404.html to the /docs folder and copy and paste the html from the index.html file into it this will resolve any build issues.

Steps

- Build Application
- Copy and Paste index.html into a new 404.html file
- Push to you GitHub repo so pages can redeploy the new build of the website

Note: this has to be done every time since building cleans the created 404.html file from the /docs folder. this works for angular applications.